# SQL Pivot based on condition

Tags: sql, pivot

Friends, I have a pivot question where in I have to convert a row into column based on certain condition. here is the sample data -

```
id    adj_product_type  dti_adj
--    ----------------  -------
1     BPM               DTI_GT45_LTE50
1     BPM               DTI_GT45
1     BPS               ABC
```

Expected output

```
id  adj_product_type  dti_adj          adj_product_type_2  dti_adj_2
--  ----------------  -------          ------------------  ---------
1   BPM               DTI_GT45_LTE50   BPS                 ABC
1   BPM               DTI_GT45
```

Requirement: Convert the BPS row as new columns.

Assumptions: There could be more than two rows when adj_product_type=BPM. There will only be one row with adj_product_type=BPS.

Sample data:

```
create table abc1 (id number,adj_product_type varchar2(100), dti_adj varchar2(100));
insert into abc1 values(1,'BPM','DTI_GT45_LTE50');
insert into abc1 values(1,'BPM','DTI_GT45');
insert into abc1 values(1,'BPS','ABC');
```

I tried using LEAD but it works only when there is only one row for BPM, any help is appreciated.

```
select 
    id,
    adj_product_type,
    dti_adj,
    lead(adj_product_type,1) over (partition by id order by adj_product_type) as adj_product_type_2,
    lead(dti_adj,1) over (partition by id order by adj_product_type) as dti_adj_2,
    rank() over(partition by id order by adj_product_type) as rnk
from 
    abc1
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. And format your tables in a way they can be read and understood, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you run a query made up of two sub-queries

- An initial query that gets the `BPM` data
- Then LEFT OUTER JOIN it to a second query with `BPS` data

However, you cannot just join on `id` (as you have found) instead, I suggest adding a `ROW_NUMBER()` value to each row in BPM data - so, for example, the first row in BPM data for id = 1 will have row_number = 1, then the second has row_number = 2, etc. Then join the BPS data onto the rows with row_number = 1.

[Here is a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IfpaeTVf) (admittedly in SQL Server) showing the logic.

Note that with your data, there isn't a clear 'sort' value that allows you to assign as the 'first' row. I've just done it based on dti_adj.

```
SELECT BPM_info.*, BPS_info.adj_product_type_2, BPS_info.dti_adj_2
FROM
  (select 
      id,
      adj_product_type,
      dti_adj,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dti_adj) AS rn 
  from 
      abc1
  where
     adj_product_type = 'BPM'
  ) AS BPM_info
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (select 
      id,
      adj_product_type AS adj_product_type_2,
      dti_adj AS dti_adj_2
  from 
      abc1
  where
     adj_product_type = 'BPS'
  ) AS BPS_info ON BPM_info.id = BPS_info.id AND BPM_info.rn = 1;
```

Results

```
id  adj_product_type   dti_adj         rn   adj_product_type_2  dti_adj_2
1   BPM                DTI_GT45        1    BPS                 ABC
1   BPM                DTI_GT45_LTE50  2    null                null
```